# How to add a list of values ​in dataframe as a new row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following columns and values ​​of the dataframe

```
df["column a"][0] = ["aks1", "aks2"]
```

I want to make two rows of that dataframe like this

```
df["column a"][0] = "aks1"
df["column a"][1] = "aks2"
```

what method can i use to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.explode("column a")
```